# JS: inject a button next to IP address

Tags: javascript, button, ip, inject

could you please help with this one? I have a page with a text that contains IP addresses, something like:

```
this is example of the text with occasional IP 8.8.8.8 and 1.1.1.1 and 123.123.123.123 so on
```

I need to be able to inject a button right next to this address like

8.8.8.8 [BUTTON]

As I see the steps:
1. Find the IP in text (can do it)
2. Somehow insert the button (this is what I cant realize since trying to use document.getElementById('')) but there is no ID so what can I do please?

Comment: So you know the steps you need to take but where is your attempt(s)? You say you can find the IP within the text... well where is the source code for that? Please update your question with the relevant source code. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the 8.8.8.8 in a span which can give you an ID and then use JS' append or similar method to inject a button.

**Like this**

this is example of the text with occasional IP `<span id="ipaddr">8.8.8.8</span>` and so on.

Comment: But I have multiply addresses at this page and somehow need a button next to each of them...

Comment: @JessicaRay, that's what JS is for.

Comment: @AjayGupta that's a good suggestion but that's all it is... this doesn't really solve anything but since the OP isn't sharing any existing/relevant source code I think this is going to be the only type of response that will be given.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="foo8.8.8.8"
var ips=str.match(/\d{1,}.\d{1,}.\d{1,}.\d{1,}/g);
var newips=new Array();
for(i=0;i<ips.length;i++){
newips[i]=ips[i]+"[button]";
var str=str.replace(ips[i],newips[i]);
}
```

Comment: I created a fiddle with the above code and made some changes. It works fine, however, there is one problem. Check it out with the browser console: https://jsfiddle.net/x1t6eza7/1/